# How could I submit the form with data attributes, SWAL, AJAX and Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that has the class `delete-modal-trigger`, and if it's submitted, an eventlistener is triggered. The form also has 2 data-* attributes, an `object` which is a json, and a `type` which would determine the controller to be called.

JS

```js
$('.delete-modal-trigger').on('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let object = JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data-object'));
    let type = event.target.getAttribute('data-type');

    let question = await Swal.fire({
        title: `Delete ${object['text']}?`,
        text: "You won't be able to revert this action!",
        icon: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#FF6666',
        cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'DELETE'
    });

    let response = function (alert) {
        if (alert.isConfirmed) {
            var url = '{{ route(":type.destroy", :id) }}';
            url = url.replace(':type', type);
            url = url.replace(':id', object['id']);
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
            });
        }
    };

    response(question);
```

The form:

```
<div>
    <form class="delete-modal-trigger" data-object="{{ $object }}" data-type="tag">
        @csrf
        <x-delete-button />
    </form>
</div>
```

But when I submit the form, I get `POST http://localhost:8000/admin/%7B%7B%20route(%22tag%22.destroy%22,%204)%20%7D%7D 404`

An example with the submission:
If type is `post` (because you want to delete a post from a blog) and the `object["id"]` is 1 (the ID of the post mentioned), then
`'{{ route("' + type + '".destroy", ' + object["id"] + ') }}',` would be

`'{{ route("post.destroy", 1) }}',` which should redirect you to the `destroy` method of the controller. If you want to delete a tag, it would be `tag.destroy`.

I know that javascript can't access the blade `route` I added as the `url`, but when what am I supposed to do with it? I'm trying to refactor my code but I'm beginning to lose hope at this point.

What would be a "good practice" for this?
Adding a `data-url` to every form would look bad, probably would work, but still it would look ugly AF.

edit#1:

It would be fine if I had the javascript in the blade template, but I don't want to have it there. It is in a separate app.js file.

Comment: No reason to use hidden field for that as I mentioned, I'm using data-* attributes which work just fine. The problem is, the eventhandler can't access the route I want (which is not solved by using a hidden input), and putting data-url="..." with blade route to every single one of these would be ugly. Also, since it's a blade template, it is defined like this: `<x-delete-modal data-object="{{ $tag }}" data-url="{{ route('admin.destroy', $tag->id) }}" />` which includes the form.

Comment: Hi, you know the actual url why not construct that thing in your code. i,e : suppose your url is `http://localhost/something/type/id` construct it using the information you can do something like this `http://localhost/something/${type}/${object['id']}` .